# How to find audio stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

how to find audio stream in ffmpeg if ffprobe showing smth like this:

```
>Input #0, rtsp, from
>'rtsp://192.168.1.15:554/live/ch00_2':   Metadata:
>title           : streamed by the macro-video rtsp server   Duration: N/A, start: 0.967000, bitrate: N/A
>Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn,
> 40 tbc
```

Already tried all channels but couldnt find it, is there a command that could scan all the possible channels to find the audio stream?
This camera has an audio output for sure, its working when im using their app. Is this possible that rtsp protocol doesnt have it? or if it doesnt is there any other way that i could grab the audio stream into ffmpeg?

Comment: What is displayed when the command is executed: ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -select_streams a <name_video_file>

Comment: Its kinda empty:

`{
    "streams": [

    ]
}
`

Comment: Thus, there are no audio streams that ffmpeg can recognize

Comment: But this camera has audio output and input also, i can record video streams with an audio, just not with ffmpeg.

Comment: Hey @FOX did you found the way to extract/find an audio stream? I have the same issue with a different kind of device, but I guess containers are identical.